# LDAP: Unable to Change Password

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryentry

I am doing the c# code to change a ldap user's password by either user himself, or the admin.
I can successfully authenticate the users. However, I get the following error message when I try to invoke a `ChangePassword` or `SetPassword` behavior:

> InnerException: The directory property cannot be found in the cache.

My code is as follows:

```
LDAPPath = "LDAP://10.29.0.1:50405/DC=DCServerName,DC=local"
LDAPAdminDN = "CN=useradmin,OU=SystemAccounts,DC=DCServerName,DC=local"
LDAPAdminPwd = "S8kf5t3!"
username = "user1"
password = "oldPassword1"
npassword = "newPassword1"

DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(
LDAPPath,
LDAPAdminDN,
LDAPAdminPwd,
AuthenticationTypes.None
);

using (root)
{
    DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root,
        string.Format("(CN={0})", username)
        );
    var result = searcher.FindOne();
    if (result != null)
    {
        var user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
        try
        {
            user.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { password, npassword });
            user.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0; 
            //user.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { npassword });
            user.CommitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string innerMsg = e.InnerException.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I am wondering how to resolve this problem to change the password successfully. Thank you guys

**Update:**
I tried several options as below but all of them don't work:
One:

```
int intPort = 50405;
user.Invoke("SetOption", new object[] { ADS_OPTION_PASSWORD_PORTNUMBER, intPort });
user.Invoke("SetOption", new object[] { ADS_OPTION_PASSWORD_METHOD, ADS_PASSWORD_ENCODE_CLEAR });
```

Two:

```
user.UsePropertyCache = true;
```

They all get error of 0x80072020

My IT guy enabled "change password on nonSSL", I am not sure any settings matter in AD LDS part.

**Question:**
Am I right to use an admin account to change a user's password in this way instead of using any impersonate code?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

    if(user != null)
    {
        user.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);
        user.UnlockAccount();
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: however, we don't have UPN set up for each user. is it a problem to use UserPrincipal?
Also we are not using AD Domain model. so ContextType is about ApplicationDirectory.

Comment: @HanYiZhang: ***NO!*** just use it - it works just fine! You can search a user by SAM Account Name, by it's display name and a few more properties - presence of a UPN is ***not*** a requirement

Comment: Thanks. Could you edit your answer for a LDAP server communication using DN? I tried to find an identity with type as DN but cannot find this user.

Comment: @HanYiZhang: [consult the relevant MSDN documentation for `PrincipalContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.aspx) to see the various overloads and methods of creating that context class

Comment: I am still waiting for an answer to my question. still prefer using DirectoryEntry Invoke to do, just want to know how to figure out the exception

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Active Directory?

```
LDAP://10.29.0.1:50405/DC=DCServerName,DC=local
```

The URL does not look right.

user.UsePropertyCache = true;
Then:
user.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { password, npassword });

-jim

Comment: Thanks Jim. this url get successful authentication of the old password. should I use the same for change password?

Comment: The issue is resolved but usepropertycache is not the issue. 
key point is: I use the admin ldap user to change user's password, I should use setpassword instead of changepassword

Comment: To reset password you set the change the LDAP unicodePwd with the new password, but you must have the correct permission to do so. You dont provide the old password. Not sure with this invoke method I am using something else and I cant work out why its not working in code.